# Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$ with $A^2(A^2 - 4 I) = 0$. What are possible minimal polynomials of $A^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form, jordan-algebras

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$ with $A^2(A^2 - 4 I) = 0$. What are possible minimal polynomials of $A^3$? Give examples of $A$ with their corresponding $A^3$ matrices.

---

At the moment I know that $f = A^2(A-2)(A+2)= 0$.
Other then that I don't really know how to get the possible minimal polynomials of $A^3$. I was thinking of maybe using the property $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$, and thus multiplying the polynomial $f$ by $g = A(A^2 + 2A + 4)(A^2 - 2A + 4)$, so that I get $f\cdot g = A^3(A^3-8)(A^3+8)=0$ (since $f=0$).

Then I can continue looking for $A^3$ with possible eigenvalues 0, 8, -8. But I don't know if this is correct, nor do I know how I would find minimal polynomials for the matrix.

Does anybody know how I can properly find the minimal polynomials and is the method of multiplying it by $g$ a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

You can greatly reduce your work by noting a couple of simple results.

Since $A^4=4A^2$ you know that $A^{12}=64A^6$. If $B=A^3$, then $B^4=64B^2$ and so $B$s minimal polynomial divides $x^4-64x^2$.

Also, since the matrices are $3\times 3$, the minimal polynomial is at most a cubic.

For each possibility check if you can find a suitable $A$ and $B$.

**Addendum**

In view of the comments below it might be helpful for me to add some general points about minimal polynomials.

The minimal polynomial $m(x)$ will divide **any** polynomial satisfied by the matrix. If you can find several polynomials the matrix has to satisfy then that will greatly reduce the possibilities.

Every root of the minimal polynomial is an eigenvalue. Again this could reduce the possibilities.

Every matrix satisfies the characteristic polynomial, $|A-xI|=0$. So $m(x)$ must divide this polynomial. (It might be considerably simpler than the characteristic polynomial.)

Comment: Oh this was one of my ideas, but I wasn't sure if it was right. Am I right in saying 0, 8, -8 are eigenvectors? How would I find suitable A and B? Do I just have to find random jordan matrices and put them in random equation? That looks like a lot of work. I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward way to calculate it?

Comment: Yes those are the only possibility for eigen**values**. They can also be seen as roots of $x^4-6x^2$.

Comment: Don't be too quick to rush to Jordan form. All the possibilities without a repeated root at zero can be given as diagonal matrices. It's very little work!

Comment: Oh, indeed turns out not to be too much work to calculate. I ended up with 5 minimal polynomials for $B$. For the diagonal matrices its easy to find $A$, but for the matrices with repeated root 0 I have a 1 underneath the diagonal. Is it possible to find an $A$, such that $A^3 = B$, because I don't know of an easy method to do this.

Comment: Let's just check the diagonal ones first. For A you have a diagonal of all 0s, all 2s, all -2s. Then there are three containing two of the three roots e.g. 0&2, etc. Finally one with all three. A total of 7.

Comment: Ohhh wow, I realise I was confused. I thought that if the minimal polynomial divided the term that the maximum multiplicity of a root was that power, but of course that is not the case since it is **a** polynomial that suites f(A) = 0. Thank you

Comment: Great! Now, when it comes to multiple roots, there's something even nicer:-

Comment: B^2=0 means A^6=0 means A^2=0 since the minimal polynomial for A only has power 2. But then B=0. In other words, B's minimal polynomial cannot have multiple roots for this particular problem. You're finished!

Comment: I understand the first sentence, but I am not sure why this means that B's minimal polynomial can't have multiple roots: if B has multiple roots, i am not sure why this means that $B^2=0$. Or are you only talking about the case that $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: It's only $0$ that can be a repeated root since it's the only repeated root in $x^4-64x^2$. My argument given above then showed that although $0$ can be a repeated root of $A$ it cannot be a repeated root of $B$.

Comment: I've added to the answer which I hope will help in seeing the value of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thank you that clears up a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help!